# How to return the parent element number upon dragstart

Tags: javascript

I have a number of div-containers containing multiple div-elements.
I'd like to get the parent number of the div-element that is being dragged

i.e. Skyler White is being dragged.
It should return "0" because it is dragged from the first subcontainer of subcontainers with the same id "subcontainer".
When Jesse Pinkman is dragged it should return a 1

```
<div id="container">
<div id="subcontainer">
<div id="0" draggable="true">Walter White</div>
<div id="1" draggable="true">Skyler White</div>
<div id="2" draggable="true">Hank Schrader</div>
</div>
<div id="subcontainer"></div>
<div id="0" draggable="true">Saul Goodman</div>
<div id="1" draggable="true">Jesse Pinkman</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [**`.index()`**](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method of `jQuery`
- Use [**`.closest`**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select the respective `closest` element of the `current` element
- Use `drag` event to select the current element

Also note that [***There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.***](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

```js
$('div[draggable]').on('drag', function() {
  $('#output').text('Parent Index is: ' + $(this).closest('.subcontainer').index());
});
```

```css
#output {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <div id="0" draggable="true">Walter White</div>
    <div id="1" draggable="true">Skyler White</div>
    <div id="2" draggable="true">Hank Schrader</div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <div id="0" draggable="true">Saul Goodman</div>
    <div id="1" draggable="true">Jesse Pinkman</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

**`JavaScript` only solution:**

- Use `[].forEach.call` to iterate `NodeList` returned by `Document.querySelectorAll()`
- Use `addEventListener` to attach `event` over each matched element
- Apply `[].slice.call` over `NodeList` so that we can invoke `indexOf` method of `Array`
- `this.parentElement` will return `parent-element` of the current element

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div[draggable]'), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('drag', function() {
    var elemsArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.subcontainer'));
    var index = elemsArray.indexOf(this.parentElement);
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = 'Parent Index is: ' + index;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#output {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <div id="0" draggable="true">Walter White</div>
    <div id="1" draggable="true">Skyler White</div>
    <div id="2" draggable="true">Hank Schrader</div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <div id="0" draggable="true">Saul Goodman</div>
    <div id="1" draggable="true">Jesse Pinkman</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, buy was actually looking for a pure js solution

Comment: Does anyone no of a pure JavaScript solution

Comment: @Ethannn – It was interesting question buddy.. I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_